# How to change the http module from angular 4 to angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I was following on of angular 4 tutorials. But I need to modify it to angular 7. But following code segment gives an error on Http module and Observable

This is the user.service.ts File

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import{Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import{Observable}   from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import{User}  from '../user';


@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  private baseUrl:string='http://localhost:8080/api';
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
  private options = new RequestOptions({headers:this.headers});
  private user = new User();
  constructor(private _http:Http) { }

  getUsers(){

    return this._http.get(this.baseUrl+'/users',this.options).map((response:Response)=>response.json())
      .catch(this.errorHandler);
  }
  getUser(id:Number){

    return this._http.get(this.baseUrl+'/user/'+id,this.options).map((response:Response)=>response.json())
      .catch(this.errorHandler);
  }
  deleteUser(id:Number){

    return this._http.delete(this.baseUrl+'/user/'+id,this.options).map((response:Response)=>response.json())
      .catch(this.errorHandler);
  }


  createUser(user:User){

    return this._http.post(this.baseUrl+'/user',JSON.stringify(user),  this.options).map((response:Response)=>response.json())
      .catch(this.errorHandler);
  }

   updateUser(user:User){

    return this._http.put(this.baseUrl+'/user',JSON.stringify(user),  this.options).map((response:Response)=>response.json())
      .catch(this.errorHandler);
  }

  errorHandler(error:Response){

     return Observable.throw(error||"SERVER ERROR");
  }

   setter(user:User){
     this.user=user;
   }

  getter(){
    return this.user;
  }
}
```

What should be changed in order to run this on angular 7? The above code segment is from angular 4. An answer is really appreciated

Comment: You forgot sbt. Matter of choice. Matter of opinion. See also [standards](https://xkcd.com/927/).

Comment: Are there any differences when it comes to security? I didn't get in "See also standards"

Comment: Maven frequently uses ant to build. I believe Gradle and sbt use maven repos. So, **no**. These tools are all open-source and leverage each other. Pick the one you like, or let your teams pick the one they like. It's entirely opinion and personal choice. Also, some make it easier to do certain things. However, "compare and contrast my personal favorite three build tools" is not an on-topic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, Maven is what is the most widely used. I actually just finished up a large Spring project in conjunction with Maven.

I work at a company that employs over 100,000 individuals, and the only support provided is for Maven (at an enterprise level). This is anecdotal, yes, but I can say that my university prioritized Maven, and all my past and present colleagues have used Maven.

This is not to say, however, that Gradle or Ant are not solid choices. There are many articles detailing the differences. See: https://www.baeldung.com/ant-maven-gradle

Comment: It helped my question Matthew

Comment: That was the official line at most of my enterprise clients, however Gradle and Apache Ivy (ant is just a build tool, ivy is their dependency manager - since we're talking about security) and sbt and even [Leiningen](https://leiningen.org/) can all use the same maven repos (and enterprises typically want to host their own maven repos). At least that has been my experience.

Comment: *"my university prioritized Maven"* That same university is probably also still teaching Java 7 even though we're now at Java 14. --- Just because you learned to use a manual screwdriver in school, doesn't mean that an electric screwdriver wouldn't be a better choice in the workplace. --- Not saying that Maven is a manual screwdriver, but schools are notoriously behind the curve, so a more up-to-date reference for choosing a build tool should be considered.

Comment: Just letting him know my experience.